# c# shift the elements of array by 1 with for loop

Tags: c#, arrays

Im making a game in c# and it have a scoreboard with the top 5 players.
I made it to work, at least I thought I did...
The script enter the value of player's name and his score in a array, but there is a problem. It just delete the last one, so if you make the best score you become #1, but the old #1 is deleted and #2 is always #2 unless someone make a result for that place. My question is how to move the array by one from some place (it depends on player's result) and delete the last string of it?

Edit: Can't use list, because im doing so much stuff with that array.
Like this:

```
string topScores = sbName[i].Substring(4);
int topScoreInt = Convert.ToInt32(topScores);
```

Comment: Can you share your source code for the insert with us so we can see what you've tried?

Comment: You'd be better off using a `List<>` and `Insert`.

Comment: I guess you are updating your list based on the index. Instead use Insert method to insert the record in the first position and delete the last one.

Comment: Don't. Just use a `SortedList`.

Comment: You have a very straightforward approach to this: make an array of six items, of which you display the first five. When a new score arrives, put it in the spot number six, and sort the array.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use an array instead of a `List` (which has a handy `Insert` method), you could work your way from the last value forward, replacing each with it's predecessor's value, until you get to the one you want to update:

```
int place = 2; // Meaning 3rd place, since arrays are zero-based

// Start at end of array, and replace each value with the one before it
for (int i = array.Length - 1; i > place; i--)
{
    array[i] = array[i - 1];
}

// Update the current place with the new score 
array[place] = score;
```

Comment: Since this is about high scores you could just use the value and move forward in the same manner as long as the score is higher than the one at the current index, and figure of the place at the same time

Comment: How are you initializing your array? It would be really helpful if you could share your code. And it looks like you should be creating some classes as well, rather than parsing array strings... that gets messy very quickly

Comment: This line: `string topScores = sbName[i].Substring(4);` could be a problem if there are less than 4 characters in `sbName[i]`.

Comment: there are never, less than 4, im using this model - URS.300 (first 3 name and after the dot the points of the player).

Comment: I was assuming that `place` started at 1, not zero in my example. I've updated my sample

Answer (score 0):

Since you have just 5 items and scoring is normally rare some basic LINQ code would be easier and likely more readable:

```
class Score { public string Name; public int Result;}
Score[] scores = new Score[5];

var newScore = new Score {Name = "Foof", Result=9001};
scores = scores
   .Where(s => s != null) // ignore empty
   .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(newScore,1)) // add new one
   .OrderByDescending(s => s.Result)  // re-sort
   .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat((Score)null,4)) // pad with empty if needed
   .Take(5) // take top X
   .ToArray(); // back to array
```

Side note: You really will be better off using `List<T>` or [`SortedList<K,V>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).